# create overlap view in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am working on React app in which I have to implement the UI which
is shown in the image so far I try to create two overlap view and button in side it. But I am not able to achieve it.
**This is what I want to achieve.** 
[image: Ouput I Want]

**This is the output of my code on two different devices** 
[image: Output on Another Device]

**output from Second** 
[image: Output on 1st Device]

**My Code:**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
    View,
    Image,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    ScrollView,
    StyleSheet,
    StatusBar
} from "react-native";
import { Col, Row, Grid } from 'react-native-easy-grid';
import { Container, Text, Button, Form, Item, Input, Label, Icon, Content } from 'native-base';

export class LoginScreen2 extends Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.wrapper} behavior="padding">
                <StatusBar hidden />
                <Image source={require('../assets/images/Amin.png')} style={styles.backgroundImage} />
                <View style={styles.scrollViewWrapper}>
                    <Image source={require('../assets/images/logo.png')} style={styles.logoStyle} />
                    <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>

                        <View
                            style={{
                                flexDirection: 'row',
                                height: 60,
                                marginTop: 45,
                                left: 0, right: 0,
                                backgroundColor: '#FFF', alignContent: 'center'
                            }}>
                            <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#A2D9CE', flex: 0.5, alignItems: 'center', borderRadius: 50, height: 60, left: 25 }} >
                                <Text> View 1</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#48C9B0', borderRadius: 50, height: 60, position: 'absolute', left: 200, top: 0, right: 25 }} ></View>

                        </View>

                    </ScrollView>
                </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>

        )
    }
}

export default LoginScreen2
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    wrapper: {
        display: "flex",
        flex: 1,
        //backgroundColor: '#76D7C4'

    },
    scrollViewWrapper: {
        marginTop: 70,
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0
    },
    avoidView: {
        paddingLeft: 30,
        paddingRight: 30,
        paddingTop: 20,
        flex: 1
    },
    loginHeader: {
        fontSize: 28,
        color: '#FFF',
        fontWeight: "300",
        marginBottom: 40
    },
    input_icon: {
        marginRight: 15,
        color: '#FFF'
    },
    backgroundImage: {
        flex: 1,
        resizeMode: 'cover', // or 'stretch'
    },
    logoStyle: {
        resizeMode: 'center',
        marginTop: 25,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',

    },
    topButton: {
        width: 100,
        marginLeft: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#A3E4D7',

    }
});
```

**I just need help on the overlapping part. Thanks in Advance**

Comment: can you try adding negative margin to the right element?
margin-left;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this
Working Example: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/intrigued-edamame

```
    import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: false,
      admin: true,
      adminColor: 'blue',
      userColor: 'green',
    };
  }

  onToggle(state) {
    console.log(state);
    if (state == 'user') {
      this.setState({
        adminColor: 'green',
        userColor: 'blue',
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        adminColor: 'blue',
        userColor: 'green',
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            borderRadius: 40,
            marginLeft:20,
            marginRight:20
          }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              width: '50%',
              backgroundColor: this.state.userColor,
              height: 60,
              borderRadius: 40,
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}
            onPress={() => {
              this.onToggle('user');
            }}>
            <Text style={{color:'white'}}>User Login</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              width: '50%',
              backgroundColor: this.state.adminColor,
              height: 60,
              borderRadius: 40,
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}
            onPress={() => {
              this.onToggle('admin');
            }}>
            <Text style={{color:'white'}}>Admin Login</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <Text style={{marginTop:30}}>Click to toggle</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks my man. You save my day. Sorry for the late reply m

Answer (score 0):

HERE IS A COMPONENT

```
const ACTIVE_COLOR = '#243E51',
  INACTIVE_COLOR = '#7B909D';
export default () => {
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.top}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => setActive(false)}>
          <View
            style={[
              styles.leftButton,
              !active && { backgroundColor: ACTIVE_COLOR, zIndex: 1 },
            ]}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>User Login</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => setActive(true)}>
          <View
            style={[
              styles.rightButton,
              active && { backgroundColor: ACTIVE_COLOR, zIndex: 1 },
            ]}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Admin Login</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <View style={styles.bottom}>
          {active ? (
            <View>
              {/*
                ADMIN LOGIN
              */}
            </View>
          ) : (
            <View>
            {/*
              USER LOGIN
            */}
            </View>
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#3B3C41',
  },
  top: {
    marginTop: 100,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    marginHorizontal: 40,
    height: 50,
  },
  leftButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: 200,
    zIndex: 0,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 25,
    backgroundColor: INACTIVE_COLOR,
    paddingRight: 60,
  },
  rightButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    right: 0,
    paddingLeft: 60,
    zIndex: 0,
    width: 200,
    borderRadius: 25,
    backgroundColor: INACTIVE_COLOR,
  },
  text: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 12,
  },
  bottom: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

go to snack: https://snack.expo.io/@ashwith00/adequate-tortilla